# Install react-toolbox in React Boilerplate causing dependency error

Tags: reactjs, dependency-management, npm-install, boilerplate, react-toolbox

I'm using react-boilerplate (https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate).

When I use "npm install --save react-toolbox" I get the following errors:

```
E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master>npm install --save react-toolbox
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "react-toolbox"
npm ERR! node v4.4.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@15.1.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-dom@15.1.0 wants react@^15.1.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-redux@4.4.5 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-router@2.4.1 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-router-scroll@0.2.0 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-addons-css-transition-group@15.1.0 wants react@^15.1.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-toolbox@0.16.2 wants react@^0.14 || ^15.0.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer enzyme@2.3.0 wants react@0.13.x || 0.14.x || ^15.0.0-0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer essence-button@1.0.8 wants react@^0.14.x

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\npm-debug.log
```

Here is the log:

```
   ...
        968 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'tools/generateMarkdown.js', 420, 438 ]
        969 verbose write writing to E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\react-toolbox\package.json
        970 info preinstall react-toolbox@0.16.2
        971 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\react-toolbox\package.json
        972 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\react-toolbox\package.json
        973 silly install resolved []
        974 verbose about to build E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\react-toolbox
        975 info build E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\react-toolbox
        976 info linkStuff react-toolbox@0.16.2
        977 silly linkStuff react-toolbox@0.16.2 has E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules as its parent node_modules
        978 verbose linkBins react-toolbox@0.16.2
        979 verbose linkMans react-toolbox@0.16.2
        980 verbose rebuildBundles react-toolbox@0.16.2
        981 info install react-toolbox@0.16.2
        982 info postinstall react-toolbox@0.16.2
        983 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\react-toolbox-ef36d0bec556668e.lock for E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\react-toolbox
        984 verbose validateInstall loading E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\package.json for validation
        985 verbose stack Error: The package react@15.1.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
        985 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:125:32
        985 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:268:7
        985 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\read-installed.js:142:5
        985 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\read-installed.js:263:14
        985 verbose stack     at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:47:24)
        985 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\read-installed.js:263:14
        985 verbose stack     at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:47:24)
        985 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\read-installed.js:263:14
        985 verbose stack     at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:47:24)
        985 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\read-installed.js:263:14
        986 verbose cwd E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master
        987 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
        988 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "react-toolbox"
        989 error node v4.4.4
        990 error npm  v2.15.1
        991 error code EPEERINVALID
        992 error peerinvalid The package react@15.1.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
        992 error peerinvalid Peer react-dom@15.1.0 wants react@^15.1.0
        992 error peerinvalid Peer react-redux@4.4.5 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0
        992 error peerinvalid Peer react-router@2.4.1 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0
        992 error peerinvalid Peer react-router-scroll@0.2.0 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0
        992 error peerinvalid Peer react-addons-css-transition-group@15.1.0 wants react@^15.1.0
        992 error peerinvalid Peer react-toolbox@0.16.2 wants react@^0.14 || ^15.0.1
        992 error peerinvalid Peer enzyme@2.3.0 wants react@0.13.x || 0.14.x || ^15.0.0-0
        992 error peerinvalid Peer essence-button@1.0.8 wants react@^0.14.x
        993 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

What is heppening here? Why I cannot install this library and how to solve this?

Comment: Try installing React 15.1.0 first, than see the output you get (essence-button@1.0.8 might be still causing problems, but will try to solve one thing at a time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

Cause:
I was using a older version of node (The LTS version recommended for the most 
users according Node's website).

Solution:
Update to a newer and current version (with npm@^3).

Where I found the solution:

https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/issues/385

Thanks to [Rogr](https://github.com/rogr) and [mxstbr](https://github.com/mxstbr)!